# HttpMessageResponse have no content in Blazor WebAssembly application

Tags: http, blazor, httpresponse, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I have developed the Blazor WebAssembly.

On click I am executing HTTP POST as follows:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, connectURl);
request.SetBrowserRequestMode(BrowserRequestMode.NoCors);
request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(contentBytes);
var response2 = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
```

And it seems to be ok, as Wireshark shows - the response is with OK status and have 186 bytes of content!

[image: wireshark shows there is data]

however, in my Blazor Wasm application I got response with empty content...

[image]

Anyone can assume the reason? Anyone can point me to some phrase I can google it? I set CORS, maybe there is something I should do additionaly?

Comment: What is response2.Status in wasm?  And is CORS applicable, ie different URLs for App and API?

Comment: Status in wasm is 0, despite via Wireshark is 200.
I thought I have disabled CORS by 3rd line in the code above. Before there was an error about no fetch data. Should I set something else?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was about CORS, but not in my Blazor application, but in the server that hosts the Blazor Application. It was necessary to include such an HTTP header in the response:

```
Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/wasm");
```